# Client denied by server configuration. Django app with mod_wsgi and apache 2.4

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions, mod-wsgi

I can't configure apache 2.4 to run wsgi application on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 installation. I use Python 3.5 and mod_wsgi 3.5 (compiled manually for both my Python and Apache) I have successfully done this before a lot of times, this time I have no clue what is the problem.

My app's config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/var/.virtualenvs/myapp python-path=/var/django/myapp
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp_error.log

    alias /static /var/django/myapp/static/
    <Directory "/var/django/myapp/static/">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/django/myapp/myapp">
            <Files "wsgi.py">
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

I always use the exact same configuration for all my Django projects, but now, every time I go to mydomain.com, I get the 403 Forbidden page. As you can see, I configured apache to log errors to `myapp_error.log`, but it logs to regular `error.log` instead:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html
```

Also, I don't understand why it says `/var/www/html`. I deleted `html` folder and even commented out

```
#<Directory /var/www/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

in Apache main config file, but I still get this messages. I checked some other config files like `000-default.conf` but found nothing related to 'html' folder.

I enabled LogLevel info and the following lines appeared in `myapp_error.log`

```
[Wed Feb 15 21:32:15.006425 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Feb 15 21:32:15.024194 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Adding '/var/django/myapp' to path.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.237501 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Shutdown requested 'myapp'.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.237561 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Stopping process 'myapp'.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.237569 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.237573 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.241445 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Terminating Python.
[Wed Feb 15 22:50:13.245683 2017] [:info] [pid 9701:tid 140288059017088] mod_wsgi (pid=9701): Python has shutdown.
```

This means that Python is running and mod_wsgi is fine.

I think this can be some kind of permission issue, but I can't figure it out exactly. `/var/django` folder is owned by me:django. www-data user is also in django group.

`wsgi.py` file permissions are

```
-rwxr-x--x  1 me django  400 Jan 20 15:32 wsgi.py
```

r-x should be enough, right? 
I tried making wsgi.py file's permissions 777, but it didn't work.

And the funniest thing that IT USED TO WORK on this server with the same configurations, and then stopped. Not sure what could go wrong. I executed git pull command to update my app's source code, did some other stuff and then I got that nasty 403 error. I can't fix it for two days. Please help.

Comment: Your ``VirtualHost`` is likely not active or not matched by your request. It is therefore falling back to the default ``VirtualHost`` (first found by Apache), which maps to default ``DocumentRoot``. That is then failing because you removed the directory default ``DocumentRoot`` refers to as well as directives which permit access to it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, oh my god, you are right! The problem was that it somehow matched the `000-default.conf` file instead of needed one. Thank you, Graham Dumpleton! I'm gonna donate mod_wsgi project now :)